# ERROR The requested URL could not be retrieved after deploying in external tomcat server

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, tomcat

I am using Spring boot to create a REST API. The API is perfectly working when I am running the project. It works for all the endpoints that I have created. However, When I deploy the application in an external tomcat I am shown an error just like the following image
[image]

But The same endpoint was working before getting deployed into tomcat.

[image]

I am unable to figure out where the problem lies. I am using
Java 8, Oracle 12C, tomcat 8.5 .
Same Problem when I used Tomcat 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue. I accidentally forgot to mention the war file/application name which must be added.